# angular parses url with LocationHashbangUrl but $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I encounter a strange behaviour with angular and html5Mode:
When i enter an url of the SPA i can see in the debugger that initally the LocationMode is *LocationHashbangUrl* even though `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is set.
So the Url is first parsed by *LocationHashbangUrl*.
Then after angular has executed `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` the url gets parsed again.

I compared this to a rather simple example implementation from this http://plnkr.co/edit/DA3Oq6?p=info there it is not the case and angular starts with LocationHtml5Url right away.

I suspect that this causes troubles with the browser back button.
When i use the backbutton of the browser i can see in the debugger that the url is first parsed again by *LocationHashbangUrl* instead of *LocationHtml5Url* and this causes a Url change to an empty path.

I use angular 1.2.28 and angular-route 1.2.28 in a requirejs context.

Btw this is a followup of [angular routes are in history but browser back jumps to first entered url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896314/angular-routes-are-in-history-but-browser-back-jumps-to-first-entered-url)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:
There was a module bootstrapped before the  actual main application and this was the reason for the inital *LocationHashbangUrl* object.

Setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in this module as well solved it.